# Viewing only the first screen's worth of output on the shell

Tags: shell-script

I am using a bash command that outputs a large quantity of data and all I need is to see the command that was run and the output that fits on the screen afterward. Is there a keyboard shortcut for this?
I would prefer to not use head or change the command at all

## Clarifying Way After the Fact

I have a bunch of different combinations of commands being run and their output displayed right after, I just want to be able to jump up to the previously run command or have commands output only a screens worth of output, but I have to copy the command after so I don't want to use head for that reason.

Comment: Could you please clarify that bit about copying over each command?

Comment: It isn't relevant. I'll just remove it - basically I just need to see the output and would rather not change the command at all

Comment: Maybe pipe to head -$LINES ? Wait, how do you expect to change what the command does? Why not a function that wraps the command?

Comment: Related: [Are there any shortcuts to jump up/down directly across the manually-typed lines of a bash terminal?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/343640)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IF** your terminal (- emulator) understands DEC VT10x console codes, you could set the scrolling region to the last two rows of the screen after clearing it:

```
echo -e "\e[2J\e[$((LINES-1));${LINES}r"
```

Your command and its output's first screen will be seen afterwards. Typing `reset` will undo the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think `tput li` shows the number of lines of your terminal window. Subtract two and then use that value with a `head -n` to show only the first *n* lines of output. That will leave your command on the first line and the prompt on the last line.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for bash involving shortcuts:

1. Start your program with big output
2. Once the screen is filled, hit `CTRL + s` to suspend output
3. To resume output, hit `CTRL + q`